# In angular 2 , Did not detect a `bs-config.json` or `bs-config.js` override file. Using lite-server defaults?

Tags: angular, typescript

I searched and didn't found an answer to this question on stackovefflow . I am new in Angular 2, I am creating a demo app but when I am doing `npm start` then this message showing on terminal/console.Though it is not doing any harm but i want to remove this error, can anyone tell me what it the meaning of this error message and how to remove this message?

message showing on console is:

**Did not detect a `bs-config.json` or `bs-config.js` override file. Using lite-server defaults.**

```
[1] Did not detect a `bs-config.json` or `bs-config.js` override file. Using lite-server defaults...
[1] ** browser-sync config **
[1] { injectChanges: false,
[1]   files: [ './**/*.{html,htm,css,js}' ],
[1]   watchOptions: { ignored: 'node_modules' },
[1]   server: { baseDir: './', middleware: [ [Function], [Function] ] } }
[0] 11:09:39 AM - Compilation complete. Watching for file changes.
[1] [BS] Access URLs:
[1]  ------------------------------------
[1]        Local: http://localhost:3000
[1]     External: http://172.18.4.98:3000
[1]  ------------------------------------
[1]           UI: http://localhost:3001
[1]  UI External: http://172.18.4.98:3001
[1]  ------------------------------------
[1] [BS] Serving files from: ./
```

See the snapshot:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

You are using lite-server which in turn uses BrowserSync. It allows you to override default server config using the `bs-config.json` or `bs-config.js` file.

Just create a `bs-config.json` or `bs-config.js` in the root directory of you app and this warning would go away. Unless you need to modify the default server config there is no need to create one.

Link to [custom configuration doc](https://github.com/johnpapa/lite-server#custom-configuration)

Answer (score 1):

Observed the same when I tried out the latest tutorial https://angular.io/guide/quickstart; back there, they briefly mentioned `bs-config.json`, but did not explicitly say that you (the reader of the tutorial) had to create that file manually (so I didn't).

Solution in my case: Scrolled down the tutorial page (link above) to the "And here are the files" section, selected `bs-config.json`, clicked "Copy Code" (copy to clipboard), and then created `bs-config.json` (in my project root folder) with the clipboard content.